# find file by size more MIN and less MAX

Tags: linux, bash, gnu-findutils

how i can use linux find command for search files that more MIN and less MAX

I tried to use the following command:

```
find . -type f -a -size +1000 -a -size -1100
```

but it does not work

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Assuming you want file sizes between 1000 and 1100 bytes:

```
find . -type f -size +1000c -a -size -1100c
```

Comment: to show these files use `find . -size +1000c -exec ls -lah $1 {} \;`